# How to call REST api in NUXT efficiently? (also at component based frontend frameworks)

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I want to get my data from server in the component where the data is needed.
(call api at `mounted` or `beforemounted` or `created` (component lifecycle loop))

If I followed the rule above, it is inevitable to call same multiple REST api at same page.

I tried to cache them but it is quite difficult to handle the REST api result.
( Because the result of REST api depends on to params and it also depends on to time....)

I know that nuxt provide fetch and async but getting all data at page level looks bad.

Is there any good strategy for call api efficiently? I think this kinds of concern is not restricted to nuxt or vue, it also happens in react, angualr like component based framework...

Answer (score 1):

If you want an SSR page than you can make API requests in the asyncData method inside pages or if you want to make API requests on client-side than you can go for mounted method.

And for state management/managing data in component/across component can be achieved via VueX

Answer (score -1):

You can use `nuxtServerInit` to store in `vuex`

Check out the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

Comment: How nuxtServerInit is related to get data by component??

Comment: You call your API in `nuxtServerInit` and store it. Call your data by using `state` or `getters` wherever you want.

Comment: I think it is not posssible get all data using nuxtServerInit and My question is that what is the good way to get data at frontend-component? Your answer is not answering...